# My delete function isn't working. How do I get it work?

Tags: python, html, oop

My delete function in Python doesn't delete my user's posts. It only takes the user back to the homepage. After clicking the "delete link" the post is supposed to disappear but it's not.

[image]

Here's the delete function in Python:

```
@app.route('/delete/post/<int:id>') 
def delete_post(id):
    if 'user_id' not in session:
        return redirect('/logout')
    data = {
        "id": id
    }
    models_post.Post.delete(data)
    return redirect('/home')
```

Here's the @classmethod code that goes with it:

```
@classmethod
def delete(cls,data):
    query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE posts.id = %(id)s;"
    return connectToMySQL(cls.db_name).query_db(query,data)
```

Here's the HTML code as well:

```
 <div class="card-body">
    {% for post in posts %}


    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <h6>Posted by: {{post.user.username}}</h6>
    <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    <a href="/edit/post/{{post.user.id}}" class="btn btn-link" value="Edit Post">Edit</a>
    <a href="/delete/post/{{post.user.id}}" class="btn btn-link" value="Delete Post">Delete</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I never get any error message after clicking the delete link, and no errors show up in my VS Code Terminal, either.

Comment: what does `connectToMySQL` return? are you missing a `commit()` after the `query`?

Comment: What does `query_db()` do? Does it call `connection.commit()`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missed committing the changes made by the query

Comment: How do you know? They haven't shown what the `query_db()` method does.